# function to sanitize mysql search string (mainly, remove wildcards)?

Tags: php, mysql, search, sql-injection

Is there a built-in php (or MySQL) function that will sanitise a string to be used in a search? In this case, I want to make a string alphabet (upper and lower) only, before it's passed into a MySQL regex.

I'm using PDO and parameterized queries, so I'm not worried about SQL injection. However, I want to make sure someone doesn't pass in wildcards and use up too much memory. So far, this is what I'm using to remove everything but spaces and the alphabet. Is this enough?

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z\s\s+]/", "", $query);
```

Comment: Please notice the *regex* bit. As far as I know, MySQL does not have a native function to escape literals in regular expressions.

Comment: Since MySQL doesn't have something, I'm using the accepted answer to sanitize the query before it's passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression you have will strip more than just the wildcards you are worried about, so I don't think it's the best solution. (You've undoubtedly heard [this quote](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html), but I'll repeat it anyhow.)

> *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions."*
>
> *Now they have two problems.*

There are built-in PHP functions that can help you with filtering. Take a look at using [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) in combination with [PHP's sanitize filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php), if you want to do something like sanitize a URL or e-mail.

However, in your case, I think the following is simplest.

```
// Are there any I missed?
$keys = array("?", "%");  
$sanitized = str_replace($keys, "", $query);
```

Comment: That is much simpler, and if I can avoid using regular expressions as much as possible when it's not necessary, I'll do so. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply removed `%` and `?`? Those are the wildcards which will matter from a memory perspective. That will afford you the most extensibility in the long run without introducing another potential for a `WTF??!` by a later developer?

For that matter, you can side-step the issue entirely by avoiding `LIKE`, but that might not be possible.

If you *must* be more selective than that, then I would exclude all `[^\w\s]+`. You don't want to exclude numbers, and there is little harm in allowing `-` and `_`.

Comment: I'm not using `LIKE`, I'm using `REGEXP` but to remove the characters you specified, would `preg_replace("(\W|\S)+", "", $query)` suffice?

Comment: Swapped it with [^\w\s]. Not sure why I wrote it the other way to begin with. But test it: `'afdasdf asdf asdf^&^(* asdf '.replace(/[^\w\s]+/,'')` => `"afdasdf asdf asdf asdf "`.

Comment: +1, this popped up as I was finishing my answer and reminded me about the '?' wildcard.